# Difference between pattern matching algorithms used in CEP and Rule Engine like drools , siddhi?

Tags: pattern-matching, drools, esper, siddhi

Pattern matching algorithms are main in rule engine or Complex Event Stream processing engine. As i studied `drools` rule engine uses `rete` algorithm for pattern matching. What does Complex Event Stream Processing engines like `siddhi` , `FlinkCEP` and `Esper`. I browsed in net i have not got any information regarding this. Please make me understand the Pattern matching used in CEP and Rule Engine. And, also what is the difference between Rule Engines and CEP, as both look similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

Esper for EPL patterns uses a dynamic state tree with bottom-up evaluation. Esper for match-recognizes uses NFA. Esper for joins and subqueries which are also often used for finding patterns in data does query planning with nested join and merge join, and builds various types of indexes automatically based on correlation criteria (hash, btree, others). Esper for matching incoming events to interested parties builds various types of indexes into a nested tree indexing the filter criteria. Esper for data windows builds a graph of operators that communicate insert and remove streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some basic info on Siddhi and how it works from the research paper[1] and its architecture from[2].

[1]https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229139642_Siddhi_A_Second_Look_at_Complex_Event_Processing_Architectures

[2]https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-architecture/